# Syntax error at or near ( error - error code 42601

Tags: npgsql

I am migrating a c# application from sql server express edition to postgresql using npgsql 4.1.3.1. However I am getting the syntax error 42601 whenever i try to add row a databound datagridview programmatically. I had a look at the update command generated by npgsqlcommandbuilder and it includes an extra parenthesis at the end.  **("pfuppersalarylimit" = @p133))**  of the command. Any help shall be highly appreciated.

```
`NpgsqlConnection con;`        
    NpgsqlCommand sqlcmd;
    NpgsqlCommandBuilder builder;
    DataSet ds;
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    public frmEmployee()
    {
        string str = Properties.Settings.Default.connectionstring; //.Settings.connectionstring2;
        con = new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection(str); // 
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void frmEmployee_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sql = "Select * from employee where company_code='S00159'  order by rownumber";
        ds = new DataSet();
        da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
        builder = new NpgsqlCommandBuilder(da);
       
        da.Fill(ds);
        bs.DataSource = ds;
        bs.DataMember = ds.Tables[0].ToString();
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
   }
   private void addemployee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       int start_row_number;
       int pos1;
       try
       {
            if (DataGridView1.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                pos1 = 0;
                start_row_number = 1; // added on 15/10/2011
            }
            else
            {
                pos1 = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1;
                start_row_number = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows[pos1 - 1].Cells["rownumber"].Value) + 1;
             }
             DataRow employeeRow = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
            string emplcode = companyInfo.company_code.Substring(1, 1) +                   classMisc.genEmployeeCodeNew(); // just a random number
            employeeRow["company_code"] = companyInfo.company_code.Trim();
            employeeRow["employee_code_no"] = emplcode;
            employeeRow["srno"] = classMisc.getsrno();
            employeeRow["flag"] = true;
            employeeRow["rownumber"] = start_row_number; // pos1
            employeeRow["mobile"] = 0;
            employeeRow["aadhar"] = 0;
            employeeRow["pfuppersalarylimit"] = 0;
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(employeeRow, pos1);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "error 1");
       }
   }
```

Comment: Can you provide some SQL and C# code? The problem might lie in a mistake you've made and not in npgsql itself - although certainly it could have a bug.

Comment: I have added the code to my question.